# Prometheus 'expected label name, got "BCLOSE"' error

Tags: java, prometheus

I have an application running on port 7070 on my local. It exposes and endpoint /metrics and shows all the tags that are available. Prometheus is not able to get these data and it says 'expected label name, got "BCLOSE"'.

I have been trying to figure this out but not sure why this code doesn't work:

```
import io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry;
import io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat;
import metrics.PrometheusRegistry;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

@Path("/metrics")
public class MetricsController {
    private final PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusRegistry = PrometheusRegistry.INSTANCE();

    @GET
    public Response getMetrics(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            TextFormat.write004(writer, prometheusRegistry.getPrometheusRegistry().metricFamilySamples());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Also, the application is neither a sprintboot nor a spring project.

Tried this:

```
    @GET
    public Response getMetrics(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
        String accept = headers.getRequestHeader("Accept").get(0);
        System.out.println("Accept Header --------------------------> " + accept);
        return Response.ok(prometheusRegistry.scrape(), "application/openmetrics-text").build();
    }
```

Even then the same error as above SS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    @GET
    public Response getMetrics() {
        return Response.ok(prometheusRegistry.scrape(), TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004).build();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).